# How to curry a Func and pass it to another Func with fewer arguments inside the constructor?

Tags: c#, delegates, functional-programming, func

I have a class that looks like this

```
 public class CacheManger<T> where T : class, new()
 {
     public CacheManger(Func<int, T> retriveFunc, Func<List<T>> loadFunc)
    {
        _retriveFunc = retriveFunc;
        _loadFunc = loadFunc;

    }
    public T GetValueByid(int id)
    {
        return _retriveFunc(id);
    }
}
```

I have another class which is as follows

```
public class AccountCache 
{

    public AccountCache ()
    {
        CacheManager = new CacheManger<Account>(GetAccount, LoadAcc);
        // LoadAcc is another method that returns a List<Account>
    }

    private Account GetAccount(int accID)
    {
        return CacheManager.CacheStore.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == accID);
        //CacheStore is the List<T> in the CacheManager.(internal datastore)
    }

    public Account GetProdServer(int accID)
    {
        return CacheManager.GetValueByid(accID);
    }  
}
```

Now as you could see I can pass `GetAccount` to the constructor of `CacheManager`. Now I have another class where i have a method like this

```
public User GetUser(string accountID, int engineID)
{

}
```

How could I pass this function to the `CacheManager`'s constructor.
I could carry the function, but then how could I pass it as a constructor argument?

What I am doing doing right now:

```
private User GetUserInternal(string accountID, int engineID)
{
    return
    /* actual code to get user */
}

private Func<string, Func<int, User>> Curry(Func<string, int, User> function)
{
    return x => y => function(x, y);
}

public UserGetAccount(string accountID, int engineID)
{
    _retriveFunc = Curry(GetUserInternal)(accountID);
    CacheManager.RetrivalFunc = _retriveFunc; //I really dont want to do this. I had to add a public property to CacheManager class for this
    return CacheManager.GetValueByid(engineID);// This will call GetUserInternal
}
```

Comment: Why do you have GetValueByid function on general cache manager? Do you need to work with all cache implementations in a generic way? If so then I would suggest to add entity key type as another generic parameter on cache manager and implement AccountId type (which is a composite key: accountId + engineId)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want partial application rather than currying.  The best way I've found is to just create N functions that take from 1-N generic parameters, then let the compiler pick the one you want.  If you take a look at my [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) project I have two functions, one called `curry` and one called `par` for currying and partial application:

[**Currying and Partial Application source**](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/main/LanguageExt.Core/Prelude/Currying%20and%20Partial%20Application)

To partially apply, do this:

```
// Example function
int AddFour(int a,int b,int c, int d)
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}

// This returns a Func<int,int,int> with the first two arguments 10 & 5 auto-provided
var tenfive = par(AddFour, 10, 5);

// res = 10 + 5 + 1 + 2
var res = tenfive(1,2);
```

To curry, do this:

```
// Example function
int AddFour(int a,int b,int c, int d)
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}

// Returns Func<int,Func<int,Func<int,Func<int,int>>>>
var f = curry(AddFour);

// res = 10 + 5 + 1 + 2
var res = f(10)(5)(1)(2);
```

Comment: This answer uses functions defined in a broken link.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu I have fixed the links.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: link broken once more, Jan 2022

Comment: Links fixed again :)